# How to customize redirect after validation in custom request class

Tags: laravel

I created custom request class in which i forbid access to specific route. Let's say I'm trying to forbid deletion of some custom category via this request class. All works well and i get redirected to 403 page. Question is, how can i customize that redirect path?

I looked over internet and saw mentions of forbiddenResponse() method, but I cant manage to get it work.

I'm using Laravel 5.7

Comment: Can you show your code with redirection logic?

Comment: With `forbiddenRespons()` i would just use `return redirect()->back()` but it doesnt work. Also, im checking `FormRequest` class which is base class for this request. There is property `$redirectRoute` which specifies a route to redirect to after validation fails, but somehow i cannt override it. In both cases i get redirected to 403 page

Answer (score 0):

If you are using named routes like

```
Route::get("/user", "UserController@index")->name('user');
```

Then you can do this.

```
return redirect()->route('user');
```

Answer (score 0):

I found some information about this. Since Laravel 5.4 `forbiddenResponse` function has been removed.

And I've managed to accomplish what I needed by changing `Handler.php` file located in `App\Exceptions` folder. In render function I'm checking if `Exception` is `AuthorizationException` after which I'm redirecting to another page.

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        if ($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException) {
            return response()->redirectTo(route('categories.index'));
        }
        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
```